# List box in c# windows phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Does list box allow **placing a paragraph of word** into it instead of a item one after another?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean?  Is your paragraph a single item, or a bunch of items you want to split by some other method for display?  An example if input & expected output would be helpful

Comment: Just a whole chunk of words. The whole listbox is just going to contain one data. "cdsfvffcdvfdsvhcfdvbchdsbvchfdbsvchdfsbvchfdjsbvchfdsbvcfdhsvbcfdjsvbcfdsvbcfhdsvbfcjdsvbcfjdschndjsvbncfdsvcfdsv"

I wanted something like a scrollable box

Comment: sounds to me you want a text block possibly inside a scroll viewer, list boxes are specifically for multiple items...

Comment: ya something like a scrollable text block which i tried to do too but not successful

Comment: did you try putting the text block inside a scroll viewer?

Comment: yes but cant be scrolled

Answer (score 5):

I think you just need to put a text block inside a scroll viewer, but this article shows how to make a control:

[See this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/priozersk/archive/2010/09/08/creating-scrollable-textblock-for-wp7.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This is some code that does the basic work:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="MyScroller">
    <TextBlock x:Name="MyTextBlock" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Some very long text here..." />
</ScrollViewer>
```

You'll see that if the area containing the text is bigger than the size of the textblock, you'll be able to scroll to view all text.